# PayPal ExpressCheckout integration problems

Tags: paypal

I'm trying to integrate Paypal's ExpressCheckout API into my website.
I'm incurring into very frustrating problems with the system and with the support assistance, too.
Every time we have a problem the support assistance invites us to change the implementation technology, from SOAP, to SDK, to NVP, etc..
After 3 days of working (from coding with SOAP (PHP) up to the attempt to start the SDK's examples) no solution has yet been found.

I'd like to know if someone has ever had similar problems. 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I completely understand and share your frustrations.

The current issue I am having is after a call to SetExpressCheckout() using the .NET SDK I redirect to the PayPal sandbox URL with the appropriate command and token specified on the querystring and when the browser gets to the PayPal site it says "Please log in to use the PayPal sandbox features" which is linked to the developer.paypal.com site.

If I log in first on another tab and then redirect to PayPal it still doesn't work, aarrggh!

Answer (score 0):

Stefano - What type of issue are you currently having?

Peter - What particular browser are you using?  There have been a few issues in the past with IE.  If you are using IE, you might try using Chrome or Firefox to see if you get different results.  I just tested all 3 and they were working for me.  You also might try clearing all cookies and cache prior to opening up a browser and navigating to developer.paypal.com.  Once you have cleared cookies and cache, open up the browser and go to developer.paypal.com and log in.  Then once logged in, on a second tab pull up your website and try testing.

Clearing the cache and cookies prior going to developer.paypal.com has worked for some merchants in the past that were having these same issues.